# Do zombies always drop carrots?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Like the title says, do zombies always drop carrots in Minecraft Pocket Edition?

Comment: I was really confused how this was unclear until I checked that edit. This is also easily researched.

Comment: The question is in an acceptable state now, so we should probably re-open... even though it is a really bad question that can be answered with a quick google.

Comment: Was it honestly worth trying to salvage this?  Seems like a lot of wasted effort for a clearly unhelpful question.

Comment: Just because the information can be found elsewhere (i.e. other sites) doesn't mean it's a bad question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a 0.8% chance for a zombie to drop 1 carrot. The chance increases with the Looting enchantment: there is a 1.2 chance with Looting I, 1.5% chance with Looting II and 1.8% chance with Looting III.

Source: [Zombie#Drops on Minecraft Gamepedia](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Zombie#Drops)

Answer (score 0):

According to the Minecraft Pocket Edition Wiki, Zombies can drop the following items:

> 0-2 (+Loot level) Rotten Flesh
>   0-1 Carrot
>   0-1 Potato
>   0-1 Iron Ingot
>   0-1 Armor Pieces
>   0-1 Iron Shovel
>   0-1 Iron Sword

This means there's 50% chance that a Zombie will drop a carrot.

Answer (score -2):

Not all the time. Many Minecraft books said carrots from zombies are a very rare drop.